# Anaconda 3 with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

**I'm installing Anaconda 3 and then creating  Tensorflow in the 'Environments'. The problem I'm facing is Anaconda 3 came with default Python 3.8, and Tensorflow requires 3.5 to 3.7.
I'm stuck on how to fulfill the requirement, the version of Tensorflow I m getting doesn't comply with Python 3.8**

https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find previous versions in Anaconda Repo:

https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

Look for 2019.07 versions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify the Python version you want while creating a new Conda environment. From the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html):

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.6
```

You can then activate this environment by calling

```
conda activate myenv
```

In this new environment, you can install TensorFlow by typing

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

---

**Edit**

You can type thee commands in the terminal or command prompt. But if you're not entirely familiar with the command line interface, you should be able to go into the Anaconda Navigator and create new environments from there.

One of the many benefits of using an environment/package manager like Conda is that you can create many virtual Python environments, each with different Python versions and packages. For instance, I might have one conda environment running on Python 3.8, and another with 3.6. The commands I've written above creates an environment named `myenv` running on Python version 3.6.

Comment: Where should I write this command, I'm new to Anaconda, please elaborate the steps

Comment: I've posted an edit. On the macOS Anaconda Navigator, there should be an "Environments" tab on the left menu bar. From there, you can create a Python environment with a version of your choice. I imagine the interface wouldn't be too different for other operations systems. Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: Glad it helped. Would appreciate an answer acceptance if you ever feel like doing it!